# Why can't compiler deduce types from templates like template<typename R(typename... Args)>?

Tags: c++, templates, functor

For me it would look natural that the compiler could deduce types of templates like this:

```
template<typename R(typename... Args)>
struct wrap {
    std::function<R(Args)> func_;

    template<typename... Args2>
    wrap(Args2&& ...args2) : func_(std::forward<Args2>(args2)...) {
    }

    R operator()(Args&&... args) {
        cout << "Extra stuff that wrap template does" << endl;
        return func_(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
}
```

So I can instantiate with any function without explicitly giving its signature to the template:

```
wrap w([](int x){ return 2*x });
```

And call it easily:

```
w(3);
```

But it turns out that this kind of wrapping does not work at all. GCC 4.8.1 says `expected nested-name-specifier before ‘R’`.

Why this is not possible? What would be the way to achieve this kind of generic wrapping functionality?

Answer (score 1):

There are proposals to do something like this in C++1y, whose state I am not current on.

Your syntax is not right for those proposals, as a lambda is the wrong type to instantiate a `std::function` template with.  It wants a signature, not the type of some lambda.

Writing a `make_wrap` is possible, but requires taking the lambda type and extracting the args and return value yourself.  It is also rarely a good idea, because if the only way you know a `std::function`s type is from deduction, in that context why type erase it?  Instead, carry the raw lambda type around.

There are reasons to want to do that, but they are rarely good.

Comment: Your argument is legit regarding the usage of std::function. For this reason I already created a simpler wrapping class (http://pastebin.com/6RhFD3Wx), but that failed when I wanted to instantiate an std::function with that wrapper given as an argument to its constructor. That is why I wanted to create a better wrapper and came up with the idea of <typename R(typename... Args)>. And this turned out to be wrong in current C++. Right?

Comment: @dennis90 you lack `const` on the operator, and have both a perfect forward and nullary overridden `()` there.  I do not know what else is wrong there.

Comment: `const` is missing only because this is an illustration of a concept. Without the nullary overriden `()`, I would not be able to call functions that take no parameters, forwarding did not compile.

Comment: Interesting, I think my "forwarding did not compile" argument is plain invalid. Maybe I overlooked something... I am now working on a wrapper that actually works and will paste it here.

Comment: @dennis90 "I don't know what is wrong, but here is an example that is what I understand to be what is going on, what is going wrong?" is rather useless.  [Simple, self contained, complete examples](http://sscce.org) are required if you don't require others to read your mind.

Comment: I think my goals in the question were clear. "Why this is not possible? **What would be the way to achieve this kind of generic wrapping functionality?**" I remove the correct answer mark because of the unhelpful, sarcastic attitude in the last comment.

Comment: @dennis90 The previous comment was a response to your comment with the link to the [incomplete example](http://pastebin.com/6RhFD3Wx) of a second problem.  Your incompetence at providing examples, which you acknowledged above, is what I was pointing out, as well as a link on how to provide useful examples.  If you don't know why something doesn't work, providing a "simplified example" that doesn't demonstrate the problem is useless.  The only way you can know your "simplified example" demonstrates the problem is if you *compile* it and ensure it *actually does demonstrate the problem*.

Comment: Sorry, that example was really improper - it was only to demonstrate a concept, and was never meant to compile. This latter fact was not obvious in my comment where I introduced it as a simple wrapper class to overcome the first problem. That was a fault of mine. As I said, now I am working on a wrapper that could potentially solve my original problem, and that wrapper is based on your idea of omitting std::function and simply storing the callable as a member variable.